# how to convert column field into blob image?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, blob, oraclereports

i have one column field in my table. The field names **'ASSET_NATIONAL_CODE'.** The field display is **'E-TANAH/PTG_NS/10/H/0001'** as a result. 
i want to convert that field into blob as barcode image. Anyone got the idea how to do that?.

```
This my query:-

select ast.asset_id,ast.ASSET_NATIONAL_CODE barcode
from 
    asset ast
where
    ast.ASSET_ID= :P_ASSET_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

First, add your BLOB column.
In order to convert VARCHAR2 to BLOB, you can use this:

```
update asset set asset_national_code_BLOB = (select utl_raw.cast_to_raw (asset_national_code) from asset where asset_id = ?)
```

Comment: i have try your way but the result display error message in oracle toad. The message error is ORA-00904: "ASSET_NATIONAL_CODE_BLOB": invalid identifier'ORA-00904: "ASSET_NATIONAL_CODE_BLOB": invalid identifier'

Comment: Indeed, "ASSET_NATIONAL_CODE_BLOB" is the name of your BLOB column/variable. Since i don't know where you want to set the result, I set it this way. Is the BLOB conversion going to be a new column or a variable ?

Comment: ok.but i just want the BLOB conversion going to be direct.i have try like this:- to_blob(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(ast.ASSET_NATIONAL_CODE)) but in my report is not support the image.is there are any way how to do that?.

Answer (score 0):

You should use some third-party solution like here [PLSQL create images](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/blog/2005/november/22.html).

Or, if you have rights to execute Java it is better to reuse Java solutions.

There is no built-in solutions to generate images with PL/SQL.